# whistle detection is not working with musicg api in android

Tags: android, audio, detection

I am trying to develop an app which detects whistle sound, I have used musicg library which is working fine but the problem is that is do no work with all the devices. How this library is working is that a recorder thread is contineously recording audio in background and a detector thread is matching the recorded buffer via whistleApi.isWhistle(buffer); method.
The problem is that above mentioned method is always returning false for some specific devices but returning true for samsung and google nexus which is right at that point.
Can anybody tell me that what should I do to resolve this issue as this is very important for my project. Help me out!

Comment: You can start by improving your question by providing context, and source code showing how your are using the library in question.

Answer (score 2):

In RecorderThread class change "AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO in CHANNEL_IN_MONO and frameByteSize=4096....

```
private AudioRecord audioRecord;
private boolean isRecording;
private int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;//CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO
private int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
private int sampleRate = 44100;//44100
private int frameByteSize = 4096; // for 1024 fft size (16bit sample size)//4096
byte[] buffer;
```